# In Word 2010 use VBA to make first document to fit page

Tags: vba, ms-word

When Word 2010 starts I would to automatically execute the VBA code

**ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitFullPage**

to make the document fit the page.

Many thanks for a tip

Answer (score 2):

You can put your command(s) in the AutoExec macro.

```
Sub AutoExec()
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitFullPage
End Sub
```

Comment: I used without activepane:
ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitFullPage

Answer (score 0):

You could add a macro like the following to the 'ThisDocument' code module of a global template (e.g. Normal.dotm):

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
With ActiveWindow
  'Reduce flickering while changing settings
  .Visible = False
  'Switch to a single view pane
  .View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone
  .View.Type = wdPrintView
  .ActivePane.View.Zoom.PageFit = wdPageFitFullPage
  'Restore the window now that we're finished
  .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```